# Why is cron catching Python's logging events as errors?

Tags: python, logging, cron

I've got a very simple test setup with cron and a Python script that uses the `logging` module, and cron is behaving oddly when it encounters a logging event.

### crontab

```
* * * * * ~/test.py >> ~/test.log
```

### ~/test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

print 'Properly printed, to file'
logging.debug("Does not get printed, get's e-mailed as an error")
print 'Still running, though'
```

### ~/test.log

After a cron run, the log is populated with these two messages:

```
Properly printed, to file
Still running, though
```

### cron Error E-mail

Also after a cron run, I get a notification that I have new mail:

```
From tomcat6@local  Thu May 23 16:35:01 2013
Date: Thu, 23 May 2013 16:35:01 -0700
From: root@local (Cron Daemon)
To: tomcat6@local
Subject: Cron <tomcat6@local> ~/test.py >> ~/test.log
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/usr/local/tomcat6>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=tomcat6>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=tomcat6>

DEBUG:root:Does not get printed, get's e-mailed as an error
```

It looks like it's not an explicit error, otherwise the final, 'Still running...', message would not be printed to `~/test.log`, right?

Why are cron and or logging doing this, and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default configuration set by `basicConfig()` logs messages to `stderr`, and cron interprets any output to the `stderr` filehandle as email-worthy; you are, after all, not redirecting it.

See the [`logging.basicConfig()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig):

> Does basic configuration for the logging system by creating a `StreamHandler` with a default `Formatter` and adding it to the root logger,

and the [`StreamHandler` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.StreamHandler):

> If *stream* is specified, the instance will use it for logging output; otherwise, `sys.stderr` will be used.

The work-around is to not set up a stream handler, or pick a different stream, or to pick a filename to log to:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename='/some/file/to/log/to')
```

or

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, stream=sys.stdout)
```

By logging to `stdout` you write logging information to the same output stream as `print()` does.

Another work-around is to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`:

```
* * * * * ~/test.py >> ~/test.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 2&>1 didn't work for me, but 2>&1 did.

Comment: @AkalankaWeerasooriya: ah, that's indeed a typo, thanks for pointing that out!