# Script only logging first line to file when run by cron job

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron

I'm having this weird issue where my Python script is only logging (using the logging module) the first line to my log file when run by cron. If I run the script myself it will log every line fine. I'm really confused as to what the issue exactly is.

Here's what my crontab looks like:

`15 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/myusername/Desktop/script.py`

Inside my script.py:

```
import logging
import otherstuff
logging.basicConfig(filename="/home/myusername/Desktop/script.log", level=logging.INFO)
logging.info("Running script...") # Only one getting logged when ran by Cron
*Other stuff that happens in script*
logging.info("Did some other stuff") # This is not getting logged when ran by Cron
```

I've tried the following:

- Set the absolute path of my log file in my script
- Changed the script's and log file's permissions so that anyone can read/write/execute.

What really confuses me is why only the first line is logged by cron. I'd understand if all the lines weren't being logged, but why is the first line the only one being logged?

Comment: Without seeing the code involved it's hard to tell what exactly what might have gone wrong (it can be a [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469117/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725714/), [3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83549/python-script-wont-write-data-when-ran-from-cron)). Note how the questions include at least some example code to satisfy the [MCVE (minimum, complete and verifiable example)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) requirements. Without further details, nobody but you can actually figure out what might have gone wrong.

Comment: Your script probaly stops by error. Add this to the end of the cron line **`15.../script.py >>/tmp/script.log`** to catch the error.